# Mysql syntax error : 'WHERE NOT LIKE'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to track the page views by inserting only unique values every 24h.But when I run this query I get a syntax error.

```
insert ignore into profilepageviews values( '77.777.777.777' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '5') where hitdate NOT LIKE '%2012-06-26%'
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where hitdate NOT LIKE '%2012-06-26%'' at line 1
```

Comment: what is ignore keyword in sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `WHERE` clause with `INSERT`, You might want [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)